# Access violation reading location in 4D dynamic array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, access-violation, dynamic-arrays, 4d

I am getting an "Access violation reading location" error in my program when trying to access
elements in my 4D dynamic array.

Here is my allocation code

```
void mazeGen(int**** mazes, int width, int height,stack<SDL_Point> backtracker)
{
    numberOfCalls++;
    //first choose a starting location for the maze
    //starting location must be odd in order to ensure that the generator does not go outside
    //the maze bounds.

    //allocate memory for the mazes
    mazes = new int***[NUMHOR];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMVER; i++)
    {
        mazes[i] = new int**[NUMVER];
    }
    //allocate memory for the actual mazes
    for (int x = 0; x < NUMHOR; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < NUMVER; y++)
        {
            mazes[x][y] = initMaze(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }
    }
    //mazeGenHelper(maze, height, width, backtracker, start);
    bool leftToRight = true;
    for (int x = 0; x < NUMHOR; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < NUMVER; y++)
        {
            //generate mazes
            SDL_Point* start = new SDL_Point();
            //genx
            do
            {
                start->x = generateRandomRange(1, width - 1);
            } while (start->x % 2 == 0);
            //gen y
            do
            {
                start->y = generateRandomRange(1, height - 1);
            } while (start->y % 2 == 0);
            //empty stack
            while (!backtracker.empty())
            {
                backtracker.pop();
            }
            mazeGenHelper(mazes[x][y], HEIGHT, WIDTH, backtracker, start);
            //delete start to prevent memory leak
            delete start;
        }
    }
}
```

Heres the rest of it(its a maze generation program in case you could not tell)

```
void mazeGenHelper(int** maze, int height, int width, stack<SDL_Point> backtracker, SDL_Point* point,SDL_Point* endPoint)
{
    numberOfCalls++;
    array<int, 4> directions = shuffleDirections();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        switch (directions[i])
        {
        case 1://up
        {
                  if (point->y - 2 > 0 && maze[point->x][point->y - 2] == 1)
                  {
                      //delete maze walls
                      maze[point->x][point->y - 1] = 0;
                      maze[point->x][point->y - 2] = 0;
                      //add current point to the backtracker
                      SDL_Point newPoint = { point->x, point->y };
                      backtracker.push(newPoint);
                      //move the current point
                      point->y -= 2;
                      mazeGenHelper(maze, height, width, backtracker, point,endPoint);
                  }
        }
        case 2://right
        {
                   if (point->x + 2 <width && maze[point->x+2][point->y] == 1)
                   {
                       //delete maze walls
                       maze[point->x+1][point->y] = 0;
                       maze[point->x+2][point->y] = 0;
                       //add current point to the backtracker
                       SDL_Point newPoint = { point->x, point->y };
                       backtracker.push(newPoint);
                       //move the current point
                       point->x += 2;
                       mazeGenHelper(maze, height, width, backtracker, point,endPoint);
                   }
        }
        case 3://down
        {
                   if (point->y + 2 < height && maze[point->x][point->y + 2] == 1)
                   {
                       //delete maze walls
                       maze[point->x][point->y + 1] = 0;
                       maze[point->x][point->y + 2] = 0;
                       //add current point to the backtracker
                       SDL_Point newPoint = { point->x, point->y };
                       backtracker.push(newPoint);
                       //move the current point
                       point->y += 2;
                       mazeGenHelper(maze, height, width, backtracker, point,endPoint);
                   }
        }
        case 4://left
        {
                  if (point->x - 2 > 0 && maze[point->x - 2][point->y] == 1)
                  {
                      //delete maze walls
                      maze[point->x - 1][point->y] = 0;
                      maze[point->x - 2][point->y] = 0;
                      //add current point to the backtracker
                      SDL_Point newPoint = { point->x, point->y };
                      backtracker.push(newPoint);
                      //move the current point
                      point->x -= 2;
                      mazeGenHelper(maze, height, width, backtracker, point,endPoint);
                  }
        }
        }
    }
    if (backtracker.size() != 0)
    {
        //pop curent element off the stack and recall
        SDL_Point newPoint = backtracker.top();
        endPoint->x = newPoint.x;
        endPoint->x = newPoint.y;
        backtracker.pop();
        mazeGenHelper(maze, height, width, backtracker, &newPoint,endPoint);
    }
    // else the maze must be done
}
```

And here is me trying to access it

```
void sdlapp::render()
{
    //clear the screen
    SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
    //do render stuff here

    //rect area for 
    SDL_Rect rect = { 0,0, zoomLevel, zoomLevel };

    //render the maze walls
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH;i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < HEIGHT; k++)
    {
        switch (maze[i][k])//<- thats where i am trying to access it.
        {
        case 1: // theres a wall
        {
                    rect.x = i * zoomLevel-camera->x;
                    rect.y = k * zoomLevel-camera->y;
                    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, mazeWallTex, NULL, &rect);
        }
            break;
        case 2: //theres a start point
        {
                    rect.x = i * zoomLevel - camera->x;
                    rect.y = k * zoomLevel - camera->y;
                    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, mazeStartTex, NULL, &rect);
        }
        case 3:
        {
                  rect.x = i * zoomLevel - camera->x;
                  rect.y = k * zoomLevel - camera->y;
                  SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, mazeEndTex, NULL, &rect);
        }
        }

    }
    //update the screen to the current render
    SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);
}
```

I don't expect you to read through all of this code but i posted it all anyway. If anyone knows what i am doing wrong could you point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time
JustinWeq,
BTW I dont really want to use vectors and can properly deal locate me memory with absoluty no memory leaks.

Comment: cant't you avoid using 4D array for maze ..

Comment: I am using a 4D array because i am generating the maze in chunks for optimization purposes and so that i can make mazes larger then 21^2 without severe loading times.

Comment: ok let me give you an example a memory can be allocated like a[m*n] and a[m][n] , first is 1D array and second is 2D array ideally it make code more confusing and hard to debug with more than 2D ...

Comment: i haven’t read the whole code, but the first thing striking out is this: You pass in an `int**** mazes` to `mazeGen`, but the first thing that function does is to discard the value passed in and replace it with a fresh allocation. If you want these allocations to be visible to the caller (which I assume you do; as it stands, that memory just leaks), you need to use `int**** &maze`. (And I still think you’d be better off without raw pointers, but this isn’t codereview.SE.)

Comment: But Arrays larger then 2D are sometimes necessary and also dynamic arrays are already impossible to debug in MS VS.

Answer (score 0):

Since it solved the problem, I’ll copy my comment here as an answer (to get the “unanswered” list a bit cleaner):

I haven’t read the whole code, but the first thing standing out is this:
You pass in an `int**** mazes` to `mazeGen`, but the first thing that function does is to discard the value passed in and replace it with a fresh allocation.

If you want these allocations to be visible to the caller (which I assume you do; as it stands, that memory just leaks), you need to use `int**** &maze`. (And I still think you’d be better off without raw pointers, but this isn’t codereview.SE.)